# How can I sort Active Directory users into mutually exclusive groups using PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to sort all Active Directory users into one of eight groups, but I cannot find an efficient and clean way of building my functions.  In practice, I've already got something that works, so my question is just for my own education.  This is my first time asking a question here, so I apologize if there's too little or too much information.

Basically, I've got to do some Active Directory logic to sort each user in my environment into one of eight groups.
Every user should be in one (and only one) of the eight groups.
Every sorting step just puts users in one category or the other.
There are three branches.
In reality, I am trying to entitle users to a VDI that matches their responsibilities.  For now, I'll pretend I'm sorting RPG criminals into equipment groups or something.

The logic is something like this:

- The criminals are all members of either the Seven Knives or Broken Gate organizations.
- The members of those organizations are all either Rogues or Fighters.
- The Rogues are all either Thieves or Assassins.
- The Fighters are all either Brutes or Champions.
- Depending on organization, class, and subclass, each criminal will have different equipment.

The end result is that users will be put into the appropriate group for their path down the tree - for example, CRIM_SK_ROG_THF, CRIM_BG_FTR_BRT, etc.  I don't have any control over this, I just have to sort them out.   I'm also not an actual programmer; I'm just a callow sysadmin that took 101-and 102-level college programming courses.

The problem I'm having is that I just can't seem to simplify my functions to one responsibility.  PowerShell lets me write more than one output, so my first pass was to just have one function that returns two lists.  It works fine, but it feels kludgy and vaguely disappointing.

```bsh
Function filter_organization ($criminals) {
    $seven_knives    =    New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $broken_gate     =    New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    forEach ($criminal in $criminals) {
        if ($criminal.MemberOf -contains "CN=Seven Knives,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm") {
            [void]$seven_knives.Add($criminal);
        }
        else {
            [void]$broken_gate.Add($criminal);
        }
    }
    Write-Output $seven_knives,$broken_gate;
}
$seven_knives, $broken_gate    =    filter_organization $all_criminals;
```

I've considered using global variables, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to decide where the taboo against them does or doesn't apply.

```bsh
Function filter_class ($seven_knives) {
    forEach ($criminal in $seven_knives) {
        if ($criminal.MemberOf -contains "CN=Fighters,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm") {
            $global:seven_knives_fighters.Add($criminal);
        }
        else {
            $global:seven_knives_rogues.Add($criminal);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also considered reference variables as parameters, but that both seems a lot like global variables and increases the parameters to three:

```bsh
$seven_knives_rogues_thieves      =    New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$seven_knives_rogues_assassins    =    New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

Function filter_subclass ($rogues, [ref]$thieves, [ref]$assassins) {
    forEach ($rogue in $rogues) {
        if ($rogue.MemberOf -contains "CN=Thieves,OU=Organizations,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm") {
            $thieves.Value.Add($rogue);
        }
        else {
            $assassins.Value.Add($rogue);
        }
    }
}
filter_subclass $seven_knives_rogues ([ref]$seven_knives_rogues_thieves) ([ref]$seven_knives_rogues_assassins);
```

But I don't particularly want to process the entire list twice for each split:

```
$criminals                =    Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter *;
$seven_knives             =    filter_seven_knives $criminals;
$broken_gate              =    filter_broken_gate $criminals;
$seven_knives_fighters    =    filter_fighters $seven_knives;
$seven_knives_rogues      =    filter_rogues $seven_knives
```

So: how can I sort these users into eight mutually exclusive groups without violating best practices, single responsibility, or DRY?  Should I forego functions and just use a ForEach loop to run every user through eight If conditions?  Is there another, more advanced concept that I will need to learn?

Comment: If you don't expect an increase in complexity just have a flat for loop. If you do expect an increase in complexity your approach does look good. Also you might be able to use a more direct approach to your `Get-ADUser`. How much overlap is there actually and what precedence do you expect? If you already assume it's exclusive a user should only match a single case, if they are not you need to think about where to put your users. Going from specific to less specific could also allow you to mark users in some way.

Comment: I think the easy way is to have a user list and all of your arraylists defined at the top. Iterate through the user list with a foreach loop. Have all the if-statement/switch logic to put users into your collections within the foreach loop. If you want something more modular, I'd go with a function that takes the user list as an input. Then it could output an object array or hash table that lists the user as one property and association as the other property. Then you can have another function or additional script logic to sort and filter users from that output object...endless flavors

Comment: I would also personally try to avoid global variables. I don't want to argue the philosophies of whether they are good or bad because there is always a use case out there. I just try to avoid them. I also don't think [ref] is necessary here either, but if it works for your overall strategy, then go for it. Even though the code looks pretty clean, [ref] does make it harder to follow if someone else has to deal with your code.

Comment: We start off with a list of all domain users.  We split them based on one group membership into _Seven Knives_ and _Everyone Else_ (Broken Gate).  Then there are five groups that could confirm them as _Fighters_; anyone not in one of those five is a _Rogue_ by default.  The subclasses are five groups per split again: any Fighter in one of those groups is a Brute, any Fighter not is a Champion.  One of five different groups can make a Rogue a Thief; any Rogue not is an Assassin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I wrote this, but here we are. Also, I didn't test this because I don't have your AD structure or your criminals.

```
function Add-UserToGroup {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]
        $Identity
    )
    try {
        # Use this to create the group name
        $StringList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
        $StringList.Add('CRIM')

        # Get the membership if it doesn't exist
        if ($null -eq $Identity.MemberOf) {
            Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity -Properties MemberOf
        }

        # Process SevenKnives/BrokenGate
        $SevenKnives = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Seven Knives,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
        $BrokenGate = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Broken Gate,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
        if ($SevenKnives -and $BrokenGate) {
            throw "Criminal '$Identity' is a member of both Seven Knives and Broken Gate"
        }
        elseif ($SevenKnives) {
            $StringList.Add('SK')
        }
        elseif ($BrokenGate) {
            $StringList.Add('BG')
        }

        # Process Rogues/Fighters
        $Rogues = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Rogues,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
        $Fighters = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Fighters,OU=Classes,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
        if ($Rogues -and $Fighters) {
            throw "Criminal '$Identity' is both a rogue and a fighter"
        }
        elseif ($Rogues) {
            $StringList.Add('ROG')

            # Process Theives/Assassins
            $Thieves = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Thieves,OU=Organizations,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
            $Assassins = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Assassins,OU=Organizations,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
            if ($Thieves -and $Assassins) {
                throw "Criminial '$Identity' is both a Thieve and an Assassian"
            }
            elseif ($Thieves) {
                $StringList.Add('THF')
            }
            elseif ($Assassins) {
                $StringList.Add('Ass')
            }
        }
        elseif ($Fighters) {
            $StringList.Add('FTR')

            # Process Brutes/Champions
            $Brutes = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Brutes,OU=Organizations,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
            $Champions = $Identity.MemberOf -contains "CN=Champions,OU=Organizations,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=Quodeth,DC=Thule,DC=dm"
            if ($Brutes -and $Champions) {
                throw "Criminial '$Identity' is both a Brute and an Champion"
            }
            elseif ($Brutes) {
                $StringList.Add('BRT')
            }
            elseif ($Champions) {
                $StringList.Add('CHP')
            }
        }

        $GroupName = $StringList -join '_'

        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Identity,"Adding to group $GroupName")) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $Identity
        }
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
}

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf | Add-UserToGroup -WhatIf
```